# Timepicker plugin for html5/jquerymobile web-app

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

Im looking for a timepicker which only includes options to set: **number of hours and number of minutes**

Note: I dont need any relation to Years/AM-PM and such.

Ive been searching around and didn't find any, maybe one of you could suggest me what shouold i use.
The plugin should mainly support iphone/android device

Examples i saw in google pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please close my topic, i didn't know this is off-topic, sorry won't happen again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second picture is the jquery mobile datepicker you can use the above format date picker by downloading the [JQM datepicker download](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/).

The following method is used to show the Time picker.

```
 <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="time" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideTimeFormat": 24}'/>
```

Here is a small demo for 24 hr datepicker.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vY9xh/1/)**</kbd>

**Note:** If you want to show the time in 24 hr format in input field you need to customize the JQM datepicker plugin. Like in `JQM-datebox-core.js` you need to set the `timeFormat : 24,`.